# Openshift : no RBAC policy matched

Tags: openshift

This is the first time I am working with Openshift. I have successfully installed Redhat Openshift on a single EC2 server ( Single Node ).
I will be installing IBM Cloud Data Pak on this Openshift Server.
I was trying to create a separate admin user for the same.
I have executed the following commands :

```
oc login -u system.admin
```

Then

```
oc create user bob
```

But I am facing the following error :

```
Error from server (Forbidden): users.user.openshift.io is forbidden: User "system.admin" cannot create users.user.openshift.io at the cluster scope: no RBAC policy matched
```

I am not able to understand the root cause of the issue.
It will be great if someone could help me to resolve this and help me understand the root cause of this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's "system:admin", not "system.admin"

And be sure client-cert and client-key is present for system:admin user in your .kube/config